# Parsing <TR> </TR> tags and printing the elements using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and I'm currently working on solving problems to improve my coding skills. I had submitted a form using python and from the next page that's displayed after submitting the form, I want to collect some data and display it in my output. The required data I want to collect is between `<TR> </TR>` tags and there are lot of `<TR> </TR>` like that in that page.

for your reference:

```
<TR class="even"><TD class="id">6422275</TD><TD class="date"><NOBR>09:06:49</NOBR><BR><NOBR>27 Feb 2016</NOBR></TD><TD class="coder"><A HREF="author.aspx?id=201837">THE_ROCK</A></TD><TD class="problem"><A HREF="problem.aspx?space=1&amp;num=1000">1000<SPAN CLASS="problemname">. A+B Problem</SPAN></A></TD><TD class="language">Python 2.7</TD><TD class="verdict_ac">Accepted</TD><TD class="test"><BR></TD><TD class="runtime">0.015</TD><TD class="memory">160 KB</TD></TR>
```

So, from the whole HTML page, I want to read the name, `THE_ROCK` (it's present in the above give tag) and if that exists in that page, I want to print the complete elements (like problem, problemname, verdict_ac, runtime and memory) in that particular `<TR> </TR>` tags. I understood that I can use `BeautifulSoup` but I don't know how to compare stuff and print the elements / tags that are needed specifically.

Code:

```
res = br.submit()
    final_url = res.geturl()
    html_doc = br.open(final_url)
    html_read = (html_doc.read())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
    for row in soup.find_all('TR'):
        print '\n'.join(row.stripped_strings)
```

I'm trying to find the `TR` tag but it was not helpful and no output is being printed.  Can someone tell me where am I doing wrong. Is my approach wrong or flow is wrong? Could you please tell me why I'm not able to get the output as expected. Thanks in advance. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When I find the text `THE_ROCK`, I want to print the whole `TR` tag in which this text exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the element by text and locate the `tr` parent using [`find_parent()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
tr = soup.find(text="THE_ROCK").find_parent("tr")
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it was very helpful! :)

Comment: One last query, so now i have all the required contents in the variable `tr`, now how do I print them separately like `<td class="date"><nobr>09:06:49</nobr><br><nobr>27 Feb 2016</nobr></br></td>,
<td class="coder"><a href="author.aspx?id=201837">THE_ROCK</a></td>,
<td class="problem"><a href="problem.aspx?space=1&amp;num=1000">1000<span class="problemname">. A+B Problem</span></a></td>,
<td class="language">Python 2.7</td>,` and so on. Can I again assign `tr` to BeautifulSoup and then parse it ?

Comment: @Dev `tr` is a `Tag` instance and you can search directly inside it using `find()` or `find_all()` or any other method that is available on the `soup` object. For example: `tr.find("td", class_="language").text`.

Comment: I was trying this - `tr_parent = soup.find(text="THE_ROCK_PYTHON").find_parent("tr")` and to print all the tags found in tr_parent, I'm using tr_parent.contents[0] but this is giving me only the first tag and not the complete list

Comment: @Dev use `tr_parent.find_all()` to find all elements inside.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(devs_html, 'html.parser')
row = soup.find_all('tr', class_='even')

In [195]: row
Out[195]: [<tr class="even"><td class="id">6422275</td><td class="date"><nobr>09:06:49</nobr><br><nobr>27 Feb 2016</nobr></br></td><td class="coder"><a href="author.aspx?id=201837">THE_ROCK</a></td><td class="problem"><a href="problem.aspx?space=1&amp;num=1000">1000<span class="problemname">. A+B Problem</span></a></td><td class="language">Python 2.7</td><td class="verdict_ac">Accepted</td><td class="test"><br/></td><td class="runtime">0.015</td><td class="memory">160 KB</td></tr>]

In [196]: row[0].contents
Out[196]: 
[<td class="id">6422275</td>,
<td class="date"><nobr>09:06:49</nobr><br><nobr>27 Feb 2016</nobr></br></td>,
<td class="coder"><a href="author.aspx?id=201837">THE_ROCK</a></td>,
<td class="problem"><a href="problem.aspx?space=1&amp;num=1000">1000<span class="problemname">. A+B Problem</span></a></td>,
<td class="language">Python 2.7</td>,
<td class="verdict_ac">Accepted</td>,
<td class="test"><br/></td>,
<td class="runtime">0.015</td>,
<td class="memory">160 KB</td>]
```

Ok, so basically we just searched for rows via the row class (: table row).  That should give you a list of rows that you can iterate over.

Just taking a single row, row[0], as an example, you can see that you have all the data () contained in the row.  To get the info out of them, you can do:

```
In [197]: row[0].find(class_='id').text
Out[197]: u'6422275'

In [198]: row[0].find(class_='coder').text
Out[198]: u'THE_ROCK'
```

And so on, until you have all the info you want.

EDIT: Ok, if you just want to find THE_ROCK and print the row:

```
for r in row:
    if 'THE_ROCK' in r.find(class_='coder').text:
        print(r)
```

That should give you the entire row, and you can do what whatever you'd like with it.

Comment: does `row[0]` mean that it's a first row? and class is not always even :( it can sometimes be odd as well. basically this is dynamically changing

Comment: row[0] is the first element in the list created by soup.find_all.  When you iterate over the list, as you do in your example above with "for row in soup.find_all('TR')", row[0] would be the first element in the iteration.  The class is probably alternating between odd/even, right?  I assume because of alternating background colors.  You can do 'soup.findall('tr', class_='even') + soup.find_all('tr', class_='odd')"

Comment: yeah correct, it is either or even. Ok I now got your login mate :) thanks

Comment: Antikantian - this is what I'm getting when i try to print the tags : `    print (tr_parent[0].find(class_='problemname').text)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bs4\element.py", line 958, in __getitem__
KeyError: 0`